# SSRS Performance issue on report server- apparently not parameter sniffing or report rendering

Tags: performance, reporting-services

This report has 7 datasets and 7 tablixes with a 1-1 correspondence. After clicking "view report" the loading icon comes up and spins indefinitely. The report never finishes or errors; I have let it run for over an hour.

Here’s what I’ve narrowed it down to:

•   Of the 7 datasets in the report, two in particular are causing the problem. If I delete both and run the report it works. If I delete all content except for EITHER of those data sets, the report hangs.

•   Both problem queries run quickly ad hoc.

•   WITH(NOLOCK) is being used on all tables in all queries.

•   I believe I have ruled out parameter sniffing:

- OPTION(RECOMPILE) has no effect.
- Hard coding parameter values in the query and running it on the report server had no effect.

•   It does not appear to be an issue with report rendering/processing. If I delete the tables using these datasets the report still loads indefinitely. If I delete the datasets themselves the report runs quickly.

•   In all cases I have been testing with the same set of parameters.

If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: How long do these queries take to run in SSMS (or equivalent)?

Comment: Most of them take <5 seconds, including one of the problem queries. The other problem query takes about 40 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried a trace on the SQL server to check exactly what is being executed on the server?

Comment: No- and I had to look that up on MSDN- but apparently I do not have permissions to run sp_trace_create.

Comment: You should be able to run a trace from SSMS. It's under Tools then SQL Server profiler.

Comment: That looks a lot like parameter sniffing. While you think you have eliminated it, it would be worth trying the two techniques I use to get around this in these answers: [SQL text expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006001/20977) and [using internal parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16929881/20977)

Comment: Are you on a development machine and running local? You know VS will cache your local data during development.

Comment: @AlanSchofield thank you for that tip, I'll be sure to get more familiar with that tool.

Comment: @RossBush I appreciate your comment but no, this is after deploying to the report server.

Comment: @ChrisLätta Thanks for those additional tips about parameter sniffing. I tried the first and it ran quickly on the report server, I'm still skeptical so I'm making sure I didn't do the expression wrong haha.

If it does turn out to be parameter sniffing what can I do? I'd rather not leave the query as an expression..

Comment: OPTION(RECOMPILE) applies only to individual commands within your stored procedure. You may still have a bad cached plan overall. To turn it off for the store procedure entirely you can use WITH RECOMPILE and totally turn off plan caching and statistics.

Comment: @VerticalSunlight It looks like you've established it is actually parameter sniffing. As to what you can do now - well, you can use a text expression to build your query and have it run fast or put up with a really slow query. The only way I've found to get around parameter sniffing is to rebuild the query from scratch in some way so Sql Server rebuilds the execution plan.